# Vue.js; Set interval does not work in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, while-loop, setinterval

I want to perform a `while` loop with one second of interval.

The method which I want to operate is;

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app14",
    data: {
        dealerCards: [],
    },
    computed: {
        dealerHand() {
            return CalcHand(this.dealerCards);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Stand: function() {
            while (this.dealerHand < 17) {
                this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
                console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);
            }
        },
    },
});
```

CalcHand returns the sum of the input array.

I rewrite it with `setInterval` function;

```
var dd = setInterval(function() {
    this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
    console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);

    if (this.dealerHand >= 17) {
        clearInterval(dd);
        return;
    }
}, 1000);
```

However, browser console said `this.dealerCards is undefined`.
I wonder if you have any idea why this error shows up.

---

I rewrote it like this. It works once a second, but not stop.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
    console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);

    if (this.dealerHand >= 17) {
        clearInterval();
        return;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: We don't have enough information. Where is `this.dealerCards` initialized? Where is `this.dealerHand` initialized?

Comment: I added the entire Vue instance.

Comment: Use an arrow function to bind the context to the Vue instance: `setInterval(() => {...})`

Comment: Thank you for helping. It is performed once a second as I expect, but it does not stop.

Comment: It has been fixed and works now, thank you. Somehow the question is closed, so I post it again. System says that this question has already answered, but I do not think so.

Comment: I have re-posted it with my answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899697/function-of-setinterval-in-vue-js